# vaadin table auto refreshing according to database

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

hi i have a Vaadin table that display data stored in Hibernate database,
is there a way to auto refreshing when a new record has inserted in the database, using indexedContainer?
thank you for help

Comment: Who is inserting the new record? Your vaadin application or some other parties?
If your app is inserting the new records then you can trigger a refresh, if some other code is inserting new records, then your app will not get a notification of the new record(s)

Comment: i try to make a listener on the database, but i'm failed...

Comment: Does your database trigger things when records are inserted/updated/deleted? (What DB type is it?)

Comment: no. this is a MySQL db

Comment: Who is inserting the new records in the database?

Comment: there in a mule application generates and insert a new records

Comment: The you will have no other choise than poll for changes. (Not a limitation of vaadin, but of the architecture)

Comment: never worked with mule, but since it is a also an ESB, why not firing a message with the changes and listen to this in your vaadin app?  then refresh e.g. via push?

Comment: Its a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483684/how-to-make-sqlcontainer-auto-refresher-in-vaadin