# How to make SQLContainer auto refresher in vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

i have a vaadin application, and i used SQLContainer to display database records.
the issue that i want to make the SQLcontainer update itself when any database change occurs.
cam anyone help me please?

Comment: Why downvote? Certainly OP wants to update his vaadin Table each time when a row is modified in his database table. I haven't found any straightforward solution to this.

Comment: According to [this page](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/sqlcontainer.caching.html#) the refresh feature is built-in: `The SQLContainer keeps continuously checking the amount of rows in the connected database table in order to detect external addition or removal of rows. By default, the table row count is assumed to remain valid for 10 seconds. This value can be altered from code; with setSizeValidMilliSeconds() in SQLContainer.` I’ve not verified this. Nor do I know if UPDATEs are detected. **IMPORTANT** You need to be using Push to have the refresh appear on client side w/o user interaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK you can't register a "listener" on changes in any database systems like MySQL, Oracle or MSSQL. Its not how databases are intended and architectured to work.

Workaround is to register JavaScript callback in Vaadin and update table every x seconds. This way you won't even need to enable PushMode - it will be still the client who will make requests to the server and not the other (dirty imo) way around.

Following example was tested on MySQL and Vaadin 7.3:

```
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    setContent(layout);
    final Table table =  new Table("Table");
    try
    {       
        JDBCConnectionPool connectionPool = new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
        QueryDelegate qd = new FreeformQuery("select * from testTable", connectionPool, "id");
        final SQLContainer c = new SQLContainer(qd);
        table.setContainerDataSource(c);           
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    layout.addComponent(table);
    JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("setInterval(function(){refreshTable();},5000);");
    JavaScript.getCurrent().addFunction("refreshTable", new JavaScriptFunction()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(JSONArray arguments) throws JSONException
        {
            table.refreshRowCache();
        }
    });
```